# Unable to set attribute in xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to set the following attributes but they do not come through correctly.

I want my xml to look like this:

```
      <AmazonEnvelope  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
```

but it shows up like this:

```
      <AmazonEnvelope  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
```

No xsi infront of the noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute of my version.

My C# code that writes the xml

```
        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        var amazonEnvelope = xmldoc.CreateElement("AmazonEnvelope");
        amazonEnvelope.SetAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "amzn-envelope.xsd");
        amazonEnvelope.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        xmldoc.AppendChild(amazonEnvelope);
```

Comment: I tried the solution but it did not work for me.  no xsi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your .NET framework version is **> 3.0** alternatively you could use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`

Namespace

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Code

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("AmazonEnvelope",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                    new XAttribute(xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "amzn-envelope.xsd")
                    )
                );
```